# appending dictionaries to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a dictionary list this

```
'main_addr': ['test@aol.com','test2@aol.com','test3@aol.com']
'sec_addr' : test4@aol.com
```

I am trying to make a list that combines all of these values so I do

```
    mylist.append(main_addr)
    mylist.append(sec_addr)
```

but when I print out mylist it is

```
    ['test@aol.com','test2@aol.com','test3@aol.com'],test4@aol.com]
```

But what I am trying to get is just a list of all the emails not a sublist, and there are time where sec_add will contain a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using append you can also use [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for the first list

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = "foo"
>>> d = []
>>> d.extend(a)
>>> d.append(b)
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 'foo']
```

Or in your case

```
mylist.extend(main_addr)
mylist.append(sec_addr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
mylist = []
d = {'main_addr': ['test@aol.com','test2@aol.com','test3@aol.com'] ,'sec_addr' : 'test4@aol.com'}
for items in d.values():
    mylist.extend(items if isinstance(items,list) else [items])

print mylist
['test@aol.com', 'test2@aol.com', 'test3@aol.com', 'test4@aol.com']
```

Comment: Why would someone use `items.__class__.__name__ == 'list'` instead of `isinstance()`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is it a bad practice to use .__class__.__name__ ??

Comment: @AnuragSharma yes it is, as .__name__ does not hold its integrity in a wrapper class. Also, it does not account for any subclasses of list, as someone may, for some unknown reason, do

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance` method to check for a dictionary value is a list or not.

```
>>> d = {'main_addr': ['test@aol.com','test2@aol.com','test3@aol.com'] ,'sec_addr' : 'test4@aol.com'}
>>> mylist = []
>>> for i in d.values():
        if isinstance(i,list):
            for x in i:
                mylist.append(x)
    else:
        mylist.append(i)


>>> mylist
['test@aol.com', 'test2@aol.com', 'test3@aol.com', 'test4@aol.com']
```

Comment: but there are times when there are more things in the dictionary and I don't want to add those to the list